# Composite pydantic model

Tags: python, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

I am writing a FastAPI application, and have the need to essentially merge some properties from two SQLAlchemy model instances into a single Pydantic model for the response, some properties from Object A and some from Object B, returning a "consolidated" object.

```python
class Message:
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  subject = Column(Text)
  message = Column(Text)

class FolderLink:
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  message_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('message.id'))
  folder_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('folder.id'))
  is_read = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
```

In application code, I have a `Message` instance, needing all properties, and the relevant `FolderLink` instance, from which I need `is_read`.

My Pydantic schema looks like:

```python
class MessageWithProperties(BaseModel):
  id: int  # from Message
  subject: str  # from Message
  message: str  # from Message
  is_read: bool  # from FolderLink
```

And in the view code, the only way I can seem to properly pass objects to the Pydantic model is like so:

```python
objs = []
# [...]
for link in links:
  objs.append({**link.message.__dict__, **link.__dict__})
```

It feels wrong to have to use a dunder method this way. I had experimented with a custom @classmethod constructor on the Pydantic model, but that will not work as I am not directly instantiating them myself, they are instantiated by FastAPI as part of the response handling.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I think you should give it a try to the alternative you mentioned: instantiate `MessageWithProperties` by yourself and return it. FastAPI should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

What if instead of mashing all the fields togther you create a top level `MessageWithProperties` class that is built from two inferior Pydantic models, one for `Message` and one for `FolderLink`? Something like:

```
class BaseSchema(pydantic.BaseModel):
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class MessageSchema(BaseSchema):
    id: int  # from Message
    subject: str  # from Message
    message: str  # from Message


class FolderLinkSchema(BaseSchema):
    is_read: bool  # from FolderLink


class CombinedSchema(BaseSchema):
    message: MessageSchema
    folderlink: FolderLinkSchema


objs = []
for link in links:
  objs.append(CombinedSchema(
      message=MessageSchema.from_orm(link.message),
      folderlink=FolderLinkSchema.from_orm(link),
  ))
```

Now you'll be able to access both the `FolderLink` and `Message`
attributes from each object in your `objs` array.

Comment: I had that thought, and it works successfully, I'm just trying to simplify the responses for the frontend, where the objects are represented together. The fact that they're separate is sort of a backend implementation detail that's to be hidden from frontend consumers